# Why did I lose this Marvel Snap match?

Tags: marvel-snap

Just finished a game of Marvel Snap (version 7.6.5) where from the end board state I feel like I should have won.

Of the three zones my opponent and I tied in one while we each won the other. Of the won zones I had the higher score, but was still defeated. If it matters my opponents final turn resolved after mine.

Given the below image can someone please explain why I lost?

[image: final board state after a game of Marvel Snap]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just figured out that in Marvel Snap tie breakers are determined by which player has the overall total power. Meaning that while each of us won a location and tied at one overall my opponent had a higher total power. In the above final board state I scored `30` while my opponent scored `32`.

The tie breaker is explained by the game’s designer Ben Brode in this video:

.